# Best model for storing list of dates | Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to store the different launch dates for my Django object for multiple regions, e.g.

object 1:

US: July 29, 2014
Asia: July 30, 2014
UK: August 1, 2014

I'm not sure what is the best model to use.

Is it better to create a different DateField field for each region, or is there a better way to group them all together in a JSON object, or other type?

I'll be displaying them together on a page. I'm expecting to run queries to show, for example, all releases in a region, or to display the first release date for that object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best model for this in my opinion is:

```
from django.db import models

class Launch(models.Model):
    region = model.CharField(max_length=20)
    date = models.DateField()
```

As simple as that.

if you happend to have another date for the same region then just create new object
`Launch.create(region=region, date=date)` and later query the way you want to display

Comment: That approach should work, thank you. I think I was just over complicating things.

I have set up the release as a separate class and used a foreign key to link back to my object.